# Two colorbars on image grid in matplotlib

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, colorbar

I would like to have the following layout in matplotlib:

Image 1a  Image 1b  Image 2a  Image 2b  Colorbar a  Colorbar b

The Colorbar a is for Image set a, and the Colobar b is for Image set b.

I have tried to use ImageGrid to create the axes for images, but no luck in making the colorbars right.  For example:

```
fig = plt.figure()
grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111, (1,6), aspect=False, share_all=False)

# Get data1a, data1b, ...

im1a = grid[0].pcolormesh(data1a)
im1b = grid[1].pcolormesh(data1b)
im2a = grid[2].pcolormesh(data2a)
im2b = grid[3].pcolormesh(data2b)

plt.colorbar(im1a, cax=grid[4])
plt.colorbar(im1b, cax=grid[5])
```

The problem with this is that the calls to colorbar() messed up with the axis limits of the images even though I specified share_all=False in ImageGrid().

Is there any tip on this?  Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, it helps to have a full working example, so that someone could copy and paste your code and reproduce your issue directly.  For example, I can see you've imported `ImageGrid`, but a full import statement would help with this, as would creating fake data sets for `data1a`, `data1b`, etc.

Also, it looks like you have a `(1,6)` where you should have `(1,4)` in your statement above:  `grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111, (1,4), aspect=False, share_all=False)`, though this is not the solution to your problem.

When I want two or more color bars, my approach is typically to use `get_position()` on an axis, which returns the coordinates for the axis corners as attributes `x0,y0,x1,y1`.  From here, I define each colorbar's axis separately and place each precisely where I want it to go.  To get this to suit your needs, you'll have to tinker with the details of `fig.add_axes([1.01, bbox_ax.y0, 0.02, bbox_ax.y1-bbox_ax.y0])` in the code below.  For example, the first two entries `1.01, bbox_ax.y0` mean "place the bottom corner at `x=1.01` and `y=bbox_ax.y0`".  The second two entries, `0.02, bbox_ax.y1-bbox_ax.y0` define the horizontal and vertical width of the colorbar axis, respectively.  I like the colorbar axes to be flush with the plot axes, so I use `bbox_ax.y1-bbox_ax.y0` for the vertical width.

Note that I'm using `mp.subplots()` instead of `ImageGrid()`, since I'm not as familiar with the latter, and I don't think it's necessary.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as mp
import numpy
import mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1

data1a = numpy.random.rand(100,100)
data1b = numpy.random.rand(100,100)
data2a = numpy.random.rand(100,100)
data2b = numpy.random.rand(100,100)

fig, axes = mp.subplots(1, 4, figsize=(8,2))

im1a = axes[0].pcolormesh(data1a, cmap='magma')
im1b = axes[1].pcolormesh(data1b, cmap='magma')
im2a = axes[2].pcolormesh(data2a, cmap='viridis')
im2b = axes[3].pcolormesh(data2b, cmap='viridis')

fig.tight_layout()

# get bounding box information for the axes (since they're in a line, you only care about the top and bottom)
bbox_ax = axes[0].get_position()

# fig.add_axes() adds the colorbar axes
# they're bounded by [x0, y0, x_width, y_width]
cbar_im1a_ax = fig.add_axes([1.01, bbox_ax.y0, 0.02, bbox_ax.y1-bbox_ax.y0])
cbar_im1a = mp.colorbar(im1a, cax=cbar_im1a_ax)

cbar_im2a_ax = fig.add_axes([1.09, bbox_ax.y0, 0.02, bbox_ax.y1-bbox_ax.y0])
cbar_im1a = mp.colorbar(im2a, cax=cbar_im2a_ax)
```

This produces the figure below:

[image]

You can also do this as a 2x2 grid with slightly different syntax:

```
fig, axes = mp.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(4,4))

im1a = axes[0,0].pcolormesh(data1a, cmap='magma')
im1b = axes[0,1].pcolormesh(data1b, cmap='magma')
im2a = axes[1,0].pcolormesh(data2a, cmap='viridis')
im2b = axes[1,1].pcolormesh(data2b, cmap='viridis')

fig.tight_layout()

bbox_ax_top = axes[0,1].get_position()
bbox_ax_bottom = axes[1,1].get_position()

cbar_im1a_ax = fig.add_axes([1.01, bbox_ax_top.y0, 0.02, bbox_ax_top.y1-bbox_ax_top.y0])
cbar_im1a = mp.colorbar(im1a, cax=cbar_im1a_ax)

cbar_im2a_ax = fig.add_axes([1.01, bbox_ax_bottom.y0, 0.02, bbox_ax_bottom.y1-bbox_ax_bottom.y0])
cbar_im1a = mp.colorbar(im2a, cax=cbar_im2a_ax)
```

Which produces this figure:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Baird, for such a thorough answer.  And I am sorry for not providing a working example.  I now understand how to use Bbox to tweak the axes to my needs.

Comment: @C.-C.Yang I'm glad it was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Using `pcolormesh`, which by default is plotted to axes with automatic aspect, does not require any special treatment to create colorbars.

The easiest way of doing so is to use a grid with unequal column width. The rest comes automatically.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=6,figsize=(7,2.2), 
                  gridspec_kw={"width_ratios":[1,1,1,1, 0.08,0.08]})
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.6)

im0  = axes[0].pcolormesh(np.random.rand(11,11), vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap="RdBu")
im1  = axes[1].pcolormesh(np.random.rand(11,11), vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap="RdBu")
im2  = axes[2].pcolormesh(np.random.rand(11,11), vmin=0, vmax=1)
im3  = axes[3].pcolormesh(np.random.rand(11,11), vmin=0, vmax=1)

axes[0].set_ylabel("y label")

fig.colorbar(im0, cax=axes[4])
fig.colorbar(im2, cax=axes[5])

plt.show()
```

[image]